# Distribution of this degree distribution plot

Tags: r, distributions, data-visualization, social-network

I have plotted this distribution, representing the degree distribution of the amazon co-purchase network (2003) graph. Sadly, I do not know how to interpret this. Do you know which distribution this is?

[image]